# Where in the linux kernel is the handling of setuid binaries implemented?

Tags: linux-kernel

I'm trying to locate the code that is responsible for changing the user and/or group id of the process when a setuid binary is `exec`'ed.

Comment: The uid/guid, generally is stored and read from the inode of the file. Therefore, you should be looking into the underlying file system code. This gets read and gets populated into the task_struct of the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is implemented in `fs/exec.c`, in `prepare_binprm()`:

```c
         /* Set-uid? */
         if (mode & S_ISUID) {
                 bprm->per_clear |= PER_CLEAR_ON_SETID;
                 bprm->cred->euid = inode->i_uid;
         }
```

<sub>(You just have to know [what to search for](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=S_ISUID).)</sub>